Html css marquee
So im tring to do an animation like a marquee
like so
my code dont work as i wont
.scrolling-text {
            display: inline-block;
            animation: scroll-text 10s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes scroll-text {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0%);
            }
            80% {
                transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 300px)); /* Adjust 300px to the container width */
            }
            90% {
                transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 300px)); /* Pause */
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateX(0%);
            }



Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you're trying to describe?

read this: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation
